# Spotify Android SDK: Play offline tracks

Tags: android, spotify, spotify-app

Is it possible to use the Spotify Android SDK for accessing and playing offline playlists/tracks/albums?

Answer (score 1):

Offline playback is not supported yet, but is coming soon. You can follow this GitHub issue for more details:

https://github.com/spotify/android-sdk/issues/2